# CSS selector for only two classes and no others

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am looking for some kind of CSS selector that will only select certain cells from a table that **only** have these two specific classes and nothing else. Here is an example for a bit more clarity.

So in this table i want to select cells A and D for styling from the row but the only distinguishable way to select them is that they don't have any classes other than .abc and .xyz. So essentially i need to fitler out any cells that have any other classes i.e. .def, .ghi.

```
<tr>
  <td class="abc xyz">A</td>
  <td class="abc xyz def">B</td>
  <td class="abc xyz ghi">C</td>
  <td class="abc xyz">D</td>
</tr>
```

Now i know i could go about it using the not selector but these classes are injected into table from an external source and new classes could be added and i don't really want to keep adding to an ever growing list of classes to ignore.

```
td.abc.xyz:not(.def),
td.abc.xyz:not(.ghi) {
  /* Style to apply */
}
```

So if anyone could point me in the right direction to anything that could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest that while this is possible in CSS, it's probably easier/more reliable in JavaScript. For example: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.abc.xyz')).filter(elem=>elem.classList.length === 2);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consider attribute selector but pay attention to whitespaces and order:

```css
[class="abc xyz"],
[class="xyz abc"] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="abc xyz">A</td>
  <td class="abc xyz def">B</td>
  <td class="abc xyz ghi">C</td>
  <td class="abc xyz">D</td>
  <td class="xyz abc">D</td>
  <td class="abc xyz ">this will fail</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If you can add some JS you can avoid the whitespace issue using `trim`

```js
var td=document.querySelectorAll('td');
for(var i=0;i<td.length;i++)
  td[i].className=td[i].className.trim();
```

```css
[class="abc xyz"],
[class="xyz abc"] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="abc xyz">A</td>
  <td class="abc xyz def">B</td>
  <td class="abc xyz ghi">C</td>
  <td class="abc xyz">D</td>
  <td class="xyz abc">D</td>
  <td class="abc xyz ">this will be good</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[class="abc xyz"], [class="xyz abc"] { … }
```